# Diagonal in matrix - python

Tags: python, matrix, range, diagonal

I need to write a function that will return the sum of numbers that form a diagonal in any given matrix. 
 Being a Python newbie I've got a problem. This is my code:

```
def diagonal(matrix):
    return sum([matrix[i][i] for i in range(len(matrix))])
```

I've been trying for some time now but don't see what is wrong because it always gives me back report about error saying "list index out of range".

I am **not** allowed to import `numpy`.

Any form of help, hint, advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this `matrix` is a square one?

Comment: What is `matrix` anyway ? Using the `matrix[i][i]` notation assumes it is a list of lists (or rather, iterables) that should be of equal sizes as pointed out by @Ray, but it's unclear from your question.

Comment: Yes, my matrix is a list of lists... And they are equal sizes.

Comment: "And they are equal sizes." that would make the matrix rectangular, but not necessarily Square. Are there the same number of lists in the list of lists as there are elements in each list?

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question. My matrix is square. So number of elements in each list equals number of lists in list.
I hope I made myself clear...

Comment: @user3036896 then you'd better provide sample matrix for which your code fails, and exact trace, as your code *should* work for square inputs.

Comment: @user3036896 yup, I just tested it on an example "matrix": `a=[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1]]` and it works no-problem. So please provide the matrix which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that your matrix is rectangular (`len(matrix[i])` is the same for all lists in `matrix`), then you can sum your list only as long as your smaller dimension goes:

```
def diagonal(matrix):
    return sum([matrix[i][i] for i in range(min(len(matrix[0]),len(matrix)))])
```

`len(matrix)` is the first dimension of your matrix, and `len(matrix[0])` is the dimension of the first row vector, which is the second dimension for rectangular matrices.

Comment: Exactly as it should be. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3036896 Notice that your sum is tricky because it may not have any meaning and the function should really be called `diagonal_or_something_else(matrix)`

Comment: OP and @Ray: Ray is right that the trace of a matrix (which is the sum of the diagonal) is not defined for non-squared matrices. But interestingly the built-in method,  [numpy.trace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html) is not restricted for squared matrices nor main diagonals. Another point that numpy is not a linear algebra module :)

Comment: @leeladam Interesting enough ha! Seems numpy trades rigorousity for usability. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop when either of indices exceds respective dimension, for example you can limit matrix with slicing:

```
def diagonal_sum(matrix):
    row_size = len(matrix[0])
    return sum(row[i] for i, row in enumerate(matrix[:row_size]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> diagonal_sum([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `diagonal` is not defined for non-square matrices. So we'd better not choose the `min` of two dimensions only to let the code return something.

So how about instead:

```
def diagonal(matrix):
    try:
        return sum([matrix[i][i] for i in range(len(matrix))])
    except IndexError:
        print "Bad Matrix! :("
```